# change the word ي to ی in jtext field

Tags: java, listener, keyrelease

i need change the word ي to ی in jtext field
if user write ي in jtext field that word must be change to ی like this
شیمي = شیمی
ي = ی
I think I should use the listener and keyrelease but I do not know how?!
or change ی to م for me?
شیمی = شیمم
every time user use ی in my jtext replace م

Comment: ي is the same as يي in Arabic. and the code for both letters whether it is in the beginning or end is the same. What you need to do here is replace all ي in the end of the sentence and this can be done using replaceAll method when a string ends with ي in the scope of JTextFeild listener method

Comment: this ي is Arabic and ی is Persian some times when importing and searching for data Creates a problem for users

Comment: `i need change the word` is the same as `in jtext field if user write` is the same as `in jtext field that word must be change to `... and its not english?

Comment: @maysamsoleymani both ي and ى are Arabic letters.

Comment: this not same ي is Arabic and ی is persian

Comment: ی = ascii = 237  and ي=ascii=236 but you can change ی to م ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find this way

```
    String a = jTextField1.getText();
    String b = a.replace("ي", "ی");
    jTextField1.setText(b);

    String c = jTextField1.getText();
    String d = c.replace("ك", "ک");
    jTextField1.setText(d);
```